# PhraseExpress - copy a clip from the history list to OS clipboard with hotkey only without mouse

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, macros, hotkeys, clipboard, phraseexpress

I need often to copy a clip from PhraseExpress clips history to the OS clipboard.

The most easy way which I was able to find needs the series of as much as SIX steps:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> => <kbd>Down</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> => <kbd>App</kbd> => <kbd>Down</kbd> => <kbd>Down</kbd> => <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It is clearly too long for a such often used operation.

**Is there an option to do the same thing with an one-step hotkey combination?**
As it seems to be logical...

Answer (score 2):

Check out the the macro function http://macro.phraseexpress.com#insertclipboard, that allows you to insert a n-th clipboard history item.

Example: `{#insertclipboard -item 3}` would insert the 3rd item of the clipboard history.

Use this macro in a phrase and apply a hotkey to that phrase.

Comment: Thank you for advice, but it's not exactly what I actually meant. 

The way you recommends would need creating an **individual hotkey (shortcut) for each of the last clips in the history list**, that means 10/20/100 clips.DIFFERENT hotkeys for the first 10/20/100 clips Also it will no allow to copy other than the first 10/20/100 clips. 

But I'd wish to get the single universal hotkey which will let me copy to the OS clipboard any clip, **which is currently selected in the list**.

Comment: We recommend to post your question in our macro questions forum at http://forum.phraseexpress.com and describe precisely, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: > We recommend to post your question in our macro questions forum at forum.phraseexpress.com          As much as I know, your forum is for registered users only, but I use currently free edition of PhraseExpress.  BTW, do you mean, that my question/request is not clear enough even although my last additional comments?